# Django + Celery + Flower seems to break RabbitMQ broker

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I've working on a fresh *headless* Debian server (Buster) with a still in dev  setup of Django (3.1.6) + Celery (4.4.7) + RabbitMQ (3.7.8) + Flower (0.9.7). (I was running with Celery 5, but downgraded to 4.4.7, because of a [bug](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029).)

Django, Celery, and Flower are Pip installed and RabbitMQ by [Debian apt-get](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html)

The code is from demo examples of [Celery First Steps with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html?highlight=django) (with names changed to spare the innocent).

I'm able to get a basic Celery example to work (see first example below). I'm also monitoring this headless server on another machine with Django/admin and RabbitMQ Management Console using ip:port. I'm trying to add Flower to this as well, but I'm encountering startup error as seen in the second Celery startup example below.

- Django Site: http://192.168.1.102:8000/admin/django_celery_beat/
- RabbitMQ Management Console: http://192.168.1.102:15672/
- Flower: http://192.168.1.102:5555/dashboard

### Starting Celery without flower argument:

```
> celery -A pyauto beat -l INFO
celery beat v4.4.7 (cliffs) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2021-02-13 19:55:19
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://<user>:**@localhost:5672/<vhost>
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
[2021-02-13 19:55:19,862: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2021-02-13 19:55:34,883: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Hello World (<myapp>.tasks.hello_world)
[2021-02-13 19:55:49,874: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Hello World (<myapp>.tasks.hello_world)
[...]
```

### Starting Celery with `flower` argument:

```
> celery flower -A pyauto beat -l INFO 
[I 210213 20:59:53 command:135] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
[I 210213 20:59:53 command:142] Broker: amqp://<user>:**@localhost:5672/<vhost>
[I 210213 20:59:53 command:143] Registered tasks:
    ['celery.accumulate',
     'celery.backend_cleanup',
     'celery.chain',
     'celery.chord',
     'celery.chord_unlock',
     'celery.chunks',
     'celery.group',
     'celery.map',
     'celery.starmap',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.add',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.count_widgets',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.hello_world',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.mul',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.rename_widget',
     'mailgoblin.tasks.xsum',
     'pyauto.celery.debug_task']
[I 210213 20:59:53 mixins:229] Connected to amqp://<user>:**@127.0.0.1:5672/<vhost>
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method stats failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method active_queues failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method active failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method reserved failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method revoked failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method conf failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method scheduled failed
[W 210213 20:59:54 inspector:42] Inspect method registered failed
[E 210213 19:56:51 broker:78] RabbitMQ management API call failed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

### To diagnose the problem I've tried:

- restart rabbitmq
- Celery github issues describe a few things

  ```
  $ celery -A pyauto inspect ping
  Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
  ```
- I don't quite understand this bit of advice from [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python_celery#RabbitMQ). Check if your default user for the service can access erlang. Doesn't quite work as expected (and it's working anyway because of the first Celery example above):

  ```
  $ su rabbitmq -c 'erl'
  This account is currently not available.
  ```
- another Celery issues recommended diagnostic, `Celery ... report`:

```
> celery -A pyauto report
software -> celery:4.4.7 (cliffs) kombu:4.6.11 py:3.8.2
            billiard:3.6.3.0 py-amqp:2.6.1
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF
            kernel version:4.19.0-13-amd64 imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:amqp results:django-db

ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES: {
 }
ADMINS: []
ALLOWED_HOSTS: ['192.168.1.101',
 '192.168.1.102',
 '127.0.0.1',
 'localhost']
APPEND_SLASH: True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS: ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS: '********'
AUTH_USER_MODEL: 'users.CustomUser'
BASE_DIR: PosixPath('/home/.../pyauto/src')
CACHES: {
 'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS: 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX: '********'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS: 600
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT: ['json']
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER: 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'amqp://<user>:********@localhost:5672/<vhost>'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'django-db'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: 'json'
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT: 1800
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED: True
CELERY_TIMEZONE: 'America/New_York'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK: 'bootstrap4'
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE: 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME: 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE: 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE: False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW: 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME: 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS: False
DATABASES: {
    'default': {   'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
                   'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
                   'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
                   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                   'HOST': '',
                   'NAME': PosixPath('/home/.../tests/pyauto/src/db.sqlite3'),
                   'OPTIONS': {},
                   'PASSWORD': '********',
                   'PORT': '',
                   'TEST': {   'CHARSET': None,
                               'COLLATION': None,
                               'MIGRATE': True,
                               'MIRROR': None,
                               'NAME': None},
                   'TIME_ZONE': None,
                   'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS: '********'
[...]
DEBUG: True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS: False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET: 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER: 'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER: 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE: 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM: 'sha256'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE: ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE: ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS: []
EMAIL_BACKEND: 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST: 'localhost'
[...]
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX: '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT: None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME: False
EMAIL_USE_SSL: False
EMAIL_USE_TLS: False
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS: None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS: ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE: 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS: 420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR: None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK: 0
FIXTURE_DIRS: []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME: None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH: None
FORM_RENDERER: 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS: []
INSTALLED_APPS: ['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_celery_results',
 'django_celery_beat',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'mailgoblin.apps.MailgoblinConfig']
INTERNAL_IPS: []
LANGUAGES: [...]
LANGUAGES_BIDI: ['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE: 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE: None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME: 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE: None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE: False
LOCALE_PATHS: []
LOGGING: {
 }
LOGGING_CONFIG: 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: 'home'
LOGIN_URL: '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL: 'home'
MANAGERS: []
MEDIA_ROOT: ''
MEDIA_URL: '/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE: 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES: {
 }
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT: 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING: 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS: '********'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT: '********'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS: '********'
PREPEND_WWW: False
ROOT_URLCONF: 'pyauto.urls'
SECRET_KEY: '********'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER: False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF: True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS: False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD: False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS: 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER: None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT: []
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY: 'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST: None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT: False
SERVER_EMAIL: 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS: 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE: 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE: 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE: False
SESSION_ENGINE: 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE: False
SESSION_FILE_PATH: None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST: False
SESSION_SERIALIZER: 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE: 'pyauto.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT: 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT: 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND: 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS: []
STATICFILES_DIRS: ['/home/.../pyauto1/src/static']
STATICFILES_FINDERS: ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE: 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT: None
STATIC_URL: '/static/'
TEMPLATES: [{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['/home/.../pyauto1/src/templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS: []
TEST_RUNNER: 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR: ','
TIME_FORMAT: 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS: ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE: 'America/New_York'
USE_I18N: True
USE_L10N: True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR: False
USE_TZ: True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST: False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT: False
WSGI_APPLICATION: 'pyauto.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS: 'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT: 'F Y'
is_overridden: <bound method Settings.is_overridden of <Settings "pyauto.settings">>
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it?